Unity + Meta Quest 3 + Passthrough in Play Mode
I am looking for this specific answer: A Unity sample that uses a Meta Quest 3 headset, and allows passthrough when pressing the Play Button in Unity. Pretty simple. Point me to it, put the answer here. Don't care about building to android and then deploying. Stop blocking my question, StackOverflow. Other people want to know this answer too.
I'm using latest Unity (6), Meta Quest Developer Hub, Meta Link (as of xmas eve 2024). I'm using a meta quest 3. meta link connected via a usb 3.0 cable. tested it, no issues. I have set up a space, defined my boundaries, the whole 9. all of that works. I'm trying to iterate in Unity in a program that uses Passthrough. I can build just fine to a binary and deploy that to the quest 3 and passthrough works. TOO SLOW. I want to press the play button in Unity and get something that is representative of how the passthrough will look, even if the latency is worse.
i have gone into Quest Link and set up all the doodads under Beta to allow passthrough. basically, everything is checked on. Under General, unknown sources is on, and openXRRuntimes is set to Meta Quest Link.
Now what I DO know works for passthrough is github's Oculus-Samples/Unity-Discover. But it uses the XR Plugin "Oculus". I chanced across this by accident. it DOES put the quest 3 into passthrough mode over Quest Link by pressing Play button in Unity. NO NEED TO DEPLOY. Yay.
Now here's the question: Starting with Unity 6, what's the minimal set of steps I need to do, in order to get/preview passthrough with the Unity's Play Button? Right now, the steps I'm trying out all result in black being seen, not passthrough. Meta's own github example, for example, using OpenXR, doesn't work. Just shows black. If I build a binary and deploy it, the passthrough works.
The meta all-in-one SDK route doesn't seem to work either.
I'm beginning to suspect that in order to preview passthrough using play mode, I must have the PC xr plugin set to "oculus", but i haven't confirmed that yet. (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mr-example-meta-openxr) This project has a main camera, and that has "AR Camera Manager" script on it, which supposedly switches it to passthrough, but...I don't see anything in that script that deals with passthrough, and it just switches it to black in play button mode. So this example confuses me.
I've tried from scratch by simply adding the OpenXR plugin, not oculus, adding the meta quest 3 features, openxr selected for both PC and Android, and setting up the project settings with Meta's suggestions for optimal efficiency. Then I upgrade the camera to an XR Rig, then i select background color = black with alpha set to 0. But I haven't used any utilities or calls to deliberately set the background mode to passthrough. So it's no wonder this approach isn't working.
